# Metafor Forest Plot with Subgroups

Tags: multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis

I'm trying to draw a forest plot after a multi-level meta-analysis that adds diamonds (polygons) for each of my subgroups (different intervention types). I have followed this code: http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/plots:forest_plot_with_subgroups, but my polygons and effect size estimates for subgroups are quite off. I think they have to be adjusted with the 'row' specifications, however, I don't understand the underlying logic of these. **Any suggestions on how to adapt the below code to make the forest plot look neat and to have the diamonds appear below each separate subgroup?**

```
MLMSavings <- rma.mv(yi=Hedge_G, V= V_g, data=Savings, random=list(~1|esid, ~1|Study._ID),  slab=paste(Study_name))



par(mar=c(2,2,2,2))
 forest(MLMSavings, main="Savings",   cex=1.2, showweights = T, xlim=c(-1.5, 1.5), at=c(-0.8, -0.6, - 0.4 , -0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8),order=order(Savings$Intervention_TYPE), rows=c(1:14,15:16,17:22,23:30), xlab ="Hedges' g Values", mlab="Grand Mean" )
 par(font=1)
  text(-1.3, 34, "Study Reference", pos = 1, font = 2)
  text (1.03, 34, "Weight", pos=1,font =2)
 text(1.3, 34, "Hedge's G [95% CI]", pos = 1, font = 2)
 abline(h = 0)




op <- par(cex=.75, font=1)
 text(-1.3, c(24,16,5), pos=4, c("Bank Account",
                                "Financial Literacy",
                                "Saving Group",
                                "Multi-Component"))




MLMSavings1<- rma.mv(yi=Hedge_G, V= V_g, data= Savings,  random=list(~1|esid, ~1|Study._ID), subset=(Intervention_TYPE== 1)) 
 MLMSavings2<- rma.mv(yi=Hedge_G, V= V_g, data= Savings,  random=list(~1|esid, ~1|Study._ID), subset=(Intervention_TYPE==2)) 
 MLMSavings3<- rma.mv(yi=Hedge_G, V= V_g, data= Savings,  random=list(~1|esid, ~1|Study._ID), subset=(Intervention_TYPE==3)) 
 MLMSavings4<- rma.mv(yi=Hedge_G, V= V_g, data= Savings,  random=list(~1|esid, ~1|Study._ID), subset=(Intervention_TYPE==4)) 


 addpoly(MLMSavings1,  row= -2, cex=.75, atransf=exp, mlab="Random Effects Model for Subgroup")
 addpoly( MLMSavings2,  row= -2, cex=.75, atransf=exp, mlab="Random Effects Model for Subgroup")
 addpoly( MLMSavings3, row = -2, cex=.75, atransf=exp, mlab="Random Effects Model for Subgroup")
 addpoly( MLMSavings4,  row= -2, cex=.75, atransf=exp, mlab="Random Effects Model for Subgroup")*
```

Comment: You should not be exponentiating Hedges' g values (i.e., remove the ``atransf=exp``). And you should be using different values for ``row`` in ``addpoly()``. Otherwise you are just plotting all of those polygons on top of each other.

Comment: Thanks, that is already really useful. But any suggestion on how I can use `row` in `addploy()` to  insert the polygons at the right place? Do the rows correspond to number of studies in my analysis?

Comment: You are copying the example too literally. In your call to forest you need to tell it which rows to use for the individual study estimates leaving gaps at appropriate places. Then when you use addpoly you supply it with the row numbers which you carefully left blank in the call to forest.

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much. Surprised that R doesn't provide a more convenient way to plot this. Stata spits out a forest plot with subgroups in a second, however, not for a multi-level meta-analysis...

Comment: There is always a trade-off between convenience and flexibility. In metafor, ``forest()`` and ``addpoly()`` are very flexible. But you have to do more 'manual' work. That's how I designed it.

Comment: It sounds like @Wolfgang and mdewey have solved your problem for you (+1s). I'll just throw out there for consideration that I've found ggplot2 to be quite handy when making forest plots that require more elaborate customization (but that just might be me). [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052000/in-ggplot2-coord-flip-and-free-scales-dont-work-together) is a related StacksOverflow question I asked awhile back that should give you an idea of what you can do with ggplot2.